# typescript - writing a function signature for multiple parameter types

Tags: typescript

I have the following:

```
const func1 = (state: Interface1){
//some code
}

const func2 = (state: Interface2){
//some other code
}

const func3: (state: Interface1|Interface2){
//some other code
}
```

but,

```
func3(func1)
```

gives me an error.

What I was trying to make was a function `func3` that can take either `func1` or `func2` as a parameter. How do I do this in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func3` expects `Interface1 | Interface2` when you want to pass `func1`.

`func1` has completely different type signature:

```js
(state: Interface1) => void
```

If you want to pass a callback, you need to change `func3` argument type:

```js
type Interface1 = {
    tag: 'Interface1'
}

type Interface2 = {
    tag: 'Interface2'
}
const func1 = (state: Interface1) => {
    //some code
}

const func2 = (state: Interface2) => {
    //some other code
}

const func3 = (cb: typeof func1 | typeof func2) => {
    //some other code
}

func3(func1) // ok
```

If you want to compose functions [this](https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose) article might be interesting for you

**UPDATE**

**Previous solutions works, but  it is impossible to call `callback`. My bad, sorry for that.**

In order to do that, you have to refactor your code a bit.
I thought that simple union type should help, but we have a deal with functions.

It is not that easy.

Consider next example:

```js
type Union = typeof func1 | typeof func2

const func3 = (cb: Union) => {
    cb({ tag: 'Interface2' }) // error
}

func3(func1) // ok
```

In above case `cb` is infered to `(arg:never)=>any`. Why ?

Please take a loot at @jcalz [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286) regarding intersection.

The main point is - that types in contravariant positions get intersected.

And because you can't create `Interface1 & Interface2` it resolved to `never`.

If you are wonder what is `contravariance`, `variance` etc ... please take a loot at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc).

So, TS does not know which argument is allowed and which is not.

As you see in the example, I have passed `func1` as an argument but tried to call callback with `Interface2` - it can throw an error in runtime.

You can handle it in this way:

```js
type Interface1 = {
    tag: 'Interface1'
}

type Interface2 = {
    tag: 'Interface2'
}


const func1 = (state: Interface1) => {
    //some code
}

const func2 = (state: Interface2) => {
    //some other code
}

type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any


function func3<Cb extends Fn, Param extends Parameters<Fn>>(cb: Cb, ...args: Param) {
    cb(args)

}

const x = func3(func1, { tag: 'Interface1' }) // ok
```

Function arguments are contravariant to each other if you want to create union of functions that why it throws an error

**UPDATE 3**

Ok, ok, this may be not what you expect.

If you still want to compute `func1` argument inside `func3`, you need to use typeguard

```js
type Interface1 = {
    tag: 'Interface1'
}

type Interface2 = {
    tag: 'Interface2'
}
const func1 = (state: Interface1) => {
    //some code
}

const func2 = (state: Interface2) => {
    //some other code
}

type Fn = (a: any) => any

// typeguard
const isFunc = <R extends typeof func1 | typeof func2>(cb: Fn, cb2: R): cb is R => cb === cb2

const func3 = (cb: typeof func1 | typeof func2) => {
    if (isFunc(cb, func1)) {
        cb({ tag: 'Interface1' })
    } else {
        cb({ tag: 'Interface2' })
    }

}

func3(func1) // ok
```

Comment: I don't know why, my IDE is giving me error, when I invoke func1 inside func3 passing to func1 a variable of type interface1 explicitly. Is this expected? It says, interface1 doesn't have some properties in interface2 and type is mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, typescript is a strict language. So you should specify the exact parameter in func3. You can do something like this:

```
type Interface1={
//some code
}
type Interface2={
//some code
}
type Interface3 = ((state:Interface1)=>void) | ((state:Interface2)=>void)

const func1 = (state: Interface1)=>{
//some code
}

const func2 = (state: Interface2)=>{
//some other code
}

const func3= (state: Interface3)=>{
//some other code
}
//both of following func3 call is correct
func3(func1);
func3(func2);
```